# Extending a formula for Pythagorean triples to even numbers

Tags: algebra-precalculus

The formula $(2n+1)^2 + (2n^2+2n)^2 = (2n^2+2n+1)^2$ gives odd Pythagorean triples for $n > 1.$
Is there an equivalent formula that produces Pythagorean triples where a is even?

Comment: Not quite clear what you mean. Shall $a$ AND $b$ be even (otherwise we can exchange the roles of $a$ and $b$)

Comment: If you want both $a$ and $b$ even, you can multiply your equation by $4 =2^2$.

Comment: Are you aware of the classification for primitive pythagorean triples?

Comment: $$a=k(m^2-n^2)$$ $$b=k(2mn)$$ $$c=k(m^2+n^2)$$ This formula gives every Pythagorean triple. So if you set $k=2n$, that might be the answer. Or, as other's have mentioned, just multiply $a, b$ and $c$ from your formula with an even number.

Comment: Can you define "odd Pythagorean triple" for us? Each triple has three integers, and either all are even, or exactly one of them is.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you mean the hypotenuse is two more than a leg, then $(2n)^2+(n^2-1)^2=(n^2+1)^2$.

$4^2+3^2=5^2$

$6^2+8^2=10^2$

$8^2+15^2=17^2$

$10^2+24^2=26^2$

$12^2+35^2=37^2$

etc.